# Running script in crontab--reboot: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, path, cron, reboot

I've set a script in my root crontab that is supposed to restart my machine with the `reboot` command.

However, I am getting a `reboot: command not found` despite the fact that `reboot` is in the root user's path.

```
$ sudo su
$ which reboot
/sbin/reboot
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

---

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1 > /dev/null 2>&1; exit_code=$?
time_stamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")

if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
    (1>&2 echo "$time_stamp: failed with exit code $exit_code; restarting now")
    reboot
else
    echo "$time_stamp: ok"
fi
```

---

root user crontab:

```
$ sudo crontab -l
58 * * * * /home/pi/github/ping-restart/ping-restart.sh >> /home/pi/github/ping-restart/cron.log 2>&1
$ sudo su
58 * * * * /home/pi/github/ping-restart/ping-restart.sh >> /home/pi/github/ping-restart/cron.log 2>&1
```

---

...yes, this is only a temporary workaround while I figure out why the internet keeps dropping.

Comment: Maybe try using the absolute path `/sbin/reboot`...

Comment: @l'L'l This seems to work. A script with `which reboot` in crontab has no output (indicating not found), while `which /sbin/reboot` has the output `/sbin/reboot`, as expected. Any idea why `reboot` by itself does not work?

Comment: Because `cron` has no clue of where the reboot command is, so you have to give the location. In `cron` only certain commands can be called using just the name, so often you need to give it the absolute path.

Comment: @l'L'l: I'm not sure I understand. I'm able to use other scripts in the root user crontab that has commands that are called by name instead of their full path (`date` as in `/bin/date`, `basename` as in `/usr/bin/basename`,`traceroute` as in `/usr/sbin/traceroute`). What's so special about `reboot`?

Comment: See Gordon's answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cron jobs run with a very basic environment setup; among other things, the default PATH is just `/usr/bin:/bin`. It does *not* use the user's regular shell setup. There are several ways to solve this:

- Use the full path in the script (i.e. `/sbin/reboot`).
- Set PATH in the script before using `reboot` (i.e. `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`).
- Set PATH in the crontab before the entry for your script (syntax is the same as in the script).

Comment: This seems 100% to be what's happening. Verified it too, setting `echo $PATH > cron_path_log` as a job.