# autorep command(belongs to autosys) not executing in crontab. Why?

Tags: bash, cron

Below is my cron entry:

```
#!/bin/bash
09 01 * * * /home/c/charlesp/jobs.sh > /home/c/charlesp/jobs1.log 2>&1
```

which gives me only the error output, but not the actual output for which the script is written. The script is working fine and giving desired output when it is executed directly, but not in cron. When it is running in crontab, the error given is below. Please help. The errors are only coming when I run them in cron; not outside of cron.

Errors:

1.When i give autorep command directly in the script:

```
/home/c/charlesp/jobs.sh: line 3: autorep: command not found
```

2.When i give autorep command along with absolute path in the script:

```
/opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/autosys/bin/autorep: error while loading shared libraries: libascmn.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My script is below:

Only autorep command:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
autorep -j ALL -L0 | grep -w RU > /home/c/charlesp/jobs.txt
```

With absolute path :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
/opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/autosys/bin/autorep -j ALL -L0 | grep -w RU > /home/c/charlesp/jobs.txt
```

Comment: By default, cron jobs run with a really minimal environment. You probably need to set `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and maybe other things. Some previous similar questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731613/running-script-in-crontab-reboot-command-not-found).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I resolved this via 

https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/224337-problem-running-autorep-command-via-crontab.html

and

https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/resource-bundle-is-not-available-while-looking-for-keycauajme80003/kb000016546

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Gordon, cron run with a minimal environment.

For Error 1:
First of all, we need to use absolute paths for everything in the script which we keep as cron entry. So complete path is given in the script like below.

/opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/autosys/bin/autorep -j ALL -L0 | grep -w RU > /home/c/charlesp/jobs.txt

Got error 2 here.

For Error 2:
Since libascmn.so is unavailable, we need to export that path where libascmn.so is present to LD_LIBRARY_PATH like below.

-bash-4.3$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/autosys/lib

Got error 3 here.

For Error 3:

Below is the error:

Resource bundle is not available while looking for key="CAUAJM_E_80003".

For this, we need to source the environment of autosys like below.

-bash-4.3$ . /opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/autouser.TQ1/autosys.sh.automgmtq1

Now, even if it does not work with .sh script, change it to .csh script.

Now the script will work like a charm in Cron.

Thank You. :)